# python spark change dataframe column data type to int error

Tags: python, apache-spark, types, casting

I want to cast the column type to int and get the first 3 rows

```
    df.withColumn("rn", rowNumber().over(windowSpec).cast('int')).where("rn"<=3).drop("rn").show()
```

but I  this error

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
.where("rn"<=3)
```

And here's how you can figure that out if you ever encounter a similar problem in the future. Following

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
```

is a Python exception and there is no `Py4JError`. This typically means you can dismiss JVM issues and focus on core Python. The only part of your code where you explicitly compare things is:

```
"rn" <= 3
```

If you want it to be a SQL literal you should pass a string:

```
.where("rn <= 3")
```

If you want `rn` to be resolved as a column use `col` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

.where(col("rn") <= 3)
```

Also `rowNumber` function has been removed in the latest release. You should use `row_number` for a forward compatibility.